# picocli : parse arguments without boiler plate

Tags: picocli

I generally store away all the command line options to a different class, say, **CliArguments**. This avoids the noise in the main class. This is what I have with *picocli*:

```java
public final class MyApp {

    private static final CliArguments cliArgs = new CliArguments();

    private MyApp() {}

    public static void main (String[] args) {
      if (parseArgs (args)) {
         new MyApp().execute();
      }
    }

    /* want to avoid this boiler plate */
    private static boolean parseArgs(String[] args) {
      CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine ( cliArgs );
      try {
        cmd.parseArgs( args );
        if (cmd.isUsageHelpRequested()) {
          cmd.usage( cmd.getOut() );
          return false;
        }
        else if ( cmd.isVersionHelpRequested() ) {
          cmd.printVersionHelp (cmd.getOut());
          return false;
        }
        logger.info("{}", cliArgs);
        return true;
     }
     catch ( ParameterException ex ) {
       logger.error ("Failure to parse : {}", ex);
       return false;
     }
   }

   private void execute() {
     // execution logic
   }
}
```

How do I avoid the boiler plate method, `pargeArgs(String[])`? The **CliArguments** class, technically, should not implement a *Callable* or *Runnable*. I can make **MyApp** be a *Callable* or *Runnable*. but to **CommandLine**, **new MyApp()** is not a command, **new CliArguments()** is.

If I want to do something like this:

```java
   final int exitCode = new CommandLine(new MyApp()).execute(args);
   if (0 != exitCode) {
     logger.error("Failed to parse");
     System.exit(exitCode);
   }
```

how do I push off all the `@Option` specification to a different class, **CliArguments** while still having the execution control in **MyApp**?

I am sure I am missing something straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is by making `CliArguments` a [mixin](https://picocli.info/#_mixins) in `MyApp`. We can then put the business logic in `MyApp`, and make it a `Runnable` or `Callable` so we can bootstrap the application with `new CommandLine(new MyApp()).execute(args)`.

For example:

```java
@Command(mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, version = "1.0.0")
public class CliArgs {
    @Option(names = "-x") boolean x;
    @Option(names = "-y") boolean y;
}

@Command(name = "myapp", description = "...")
public class MyApp implements Runnable {

    // options defined in the mixin are added to this command
    // also, @Command attributes from the mixin are applied to this command
    @Mixin
    CliArgs cliArgs;

    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("-x=%s%n", cliArgs.x);
        System.out.printf("-y=%s%n", cliArgs.y);
    }

    public void main(String... args) {
        System.exit(new CommandLine(new MyApp()).execute(args));
    }
}
```

The options defined in the `CliArgs` mixin become part of the `MyApp` mixee.
Also, any `@Command` attributes defined in `CliArgs` become part of the `MyApp` command.

You can now run:

```
java MyApp -x
```

and this will print

```
-x=true
-y=false
```

Since the mixin has `@Command(mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)`, the `MyApp` command also has `--help` and `--version` options that work as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks, ```@Mixin``` was the thing I was missing.

Btw, the github example, [CommandWithMixin.java](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/picocli-examples/src/main/java/picocli/examples/mixin/CommandWithMixin.java), is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. What is the GitHub example missing? I can see the mixin class [CommonOption.java](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/picocli-examples/src/main/java/picocli/examples/mixin/CommonOption.java), or is that not what you mean?

Comment: Github was giving a server error on the CommandWithMixin.java file. I can see it now. No issues. Thanks, agian.